# How can one put results of 5 threads into Label text?

Tags: java, swing

I have following code for making GridLayout. There are 5 labels.
I need to make 5 threads of CoinFlip and set text of labels as results.

I have no idea where to start, sorry about not being specific. 
Thanks in advance!

```
public class GrLayout {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Coin Flip Results");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("1");  
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("2");
JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("3");
JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("4");
JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("5");

public GrLayout() {
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
    panel.add(lbl1);
    panel.add(lbl2);
    panel.add(lbl3);
    panel.add(lbl4);
    panel.add(lbl5);
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setSize(500, 100);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new GrLayout();             
        }           
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Firstly I am happy that someone is still working on Java Swing in 2019. (y)

Comment: Can you plz be a a little bit more specific!? What is the expected behaviour of this CoinFlip stuff? What should be displayed and when?

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider CoinFlip should randomly return TRUE or FALSE value.
I should make 5 threads that will get 5 results and then write the results on the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple example how you COULD implement this:

- code that needs to be run in a separate thread should be encapsulated in a class that implements interface `java.lang.Runnable`, inside it's `public void run()`method. So in your case, that's were the "complex" coinflipping logic comes - complex, computing intense stuff should never happen on Swings so called `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` because this may freeze your GUI and doesn't feel smooth ;-)
- next important part: call UI related operations ON the Event Dispatch Thread... this can be achieved by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

To keep things simple and short in this example I created a subclass of `javax.swing.JLabel` and let it implement the `java.lang.Runnable` interface. In the `CoinFlipApp` class I got an `ExecutorService` instance - think of it as a threadpool. To get things executed in separate threads by this threadpool you have to pass it a `Runnable` which will then be scheduled for execution. This happens by calling `executorService.submit(coinFlip);`

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CoinFlipApp extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            LayoutManager layoutManager = new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
            f.getContentPane().setLayout(layoutManager);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
            for (int i=0, j=5; i<j; i++) {
                CoinFlip coinFlip = new CoinFlip();
                f.getContentPane().add(coinFlip);
                executorService.submit(coinFlip);
            }
        });
    }
}



import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CoinFlip extends JLabel implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String value = Boolean.toString(randomBoolean()).toUpperCase();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            CoinFlip.this.setText(value);
            CoinFlip.this.repaint();
        });
    }

    private boolean randomBoolean() {
        try {
            // this can be removed later
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Math.random() < 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot mate!!!